# Efficient way to parsing the image urls (from server)and storing it into internal storage?

Tags: php, android, web-services

In app's first launch it is downloading the data from server which includes text and image urls
I want to download the images from url and store it into internal storage of android device (don't want to use glide or picasso  library).

My application is working fine but it is taking around 1 min to load the data from server due to async task which is being called for each url.
Can anyone help me with the efficient way to do this.
I have added my code bellow

```
   private void dataUpdation() {
    if (!doesDatabaseExist(this, "localdb_final")) {

        WebservicesCallingClass.insertValues(this, new ServerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {

                addAllDataInDatabase(result, getApplicationContext());

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setAdapters();

            }
        });
    } else {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        catArrayList=MyDBHandler.getInstance(context).getAllCategories();
        customAdapter=new CategoryGridAdapter();
        customAdapter.setItems(catArrayList);
    }
}
```

AddAllDataInDatabase method

```
 public void addAllDataInDatabase(String result, Context context) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(result);
        try {
            JSONArray jsonCatArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("category");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonCatArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonCatArray.get(i);
                String path = null;
                ConvertImage task = new ConvertImage();
                MyTaskParams params = new MyTaskParams(obj.getString("category"), obj.getString("category_image"));
                task.execute(params);
                try {
                    path = task.get();
                    System.out.print("PATH" + path);
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                CategoryDBPojo categoryDBPojo = new CategoryDBPojo(obj.getString("category"), obj.getInt("category_id"), path);
                MyDBHandler.getInstance(context).addCategory(categoryDBPojo);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "add all data" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            JSONArray jsonSubcatArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("subcategory");
            for (
                    int i = 0; i < jsonSubcatArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonSubcatArray.get(i);
                SubcategoryDBPojo subcategoryDBPojo = new SubcategoryDBPojo(obj.getString("subcategory"), obj.getInt("category_id"), obj.getInt("subcategory_id"));
                MyDBHandler.getInstance(context).addSubCategory(subcategoryDBPojo);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            JSONArray jsonLinksArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("link");
            for (
                    int i = 0; i < jsonLinksArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonLinksArray.get(i);
                String path = null;
                LinksDBPojo linksDBPojo = null;
                ConvertImage task = new ConvertImage();
                if (StoredImage.loadImageFromStorage(getFilePath(), obj.getString("site_name")) == null) {
                    MyTaskParams params = new MyTaskParams(obj.getString("site_name"), obj.getString("image"));
                    task.execute(params);
                    try {
                        path = task.get();
                        System.out.print("PATH" + path);
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    linksDBPojo = new LinksDBPojo(obj.getString("site_url"), obj.getString("site_name"), path, obj.getInt("subcategory_id"), obj.getInt("link_id"));

                } else {
                    linksDBPojo = new LinksDBPojo(obj.getString("site_url"), obj.getString("site_name"), getFilePath(), obj.getInt("subcategory_id"), obj.getInt("link_id"));
                }
                MyDBHandler.getInstance(context).addLinks(linksDBPojo);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ConverImage Async Class

```
public class ConvertImage extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, String> {


    HttpURLConnection connection;
    String path;

    protected String doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {

        try {
            String category = params[0].category;

            URL url = new URL(params[0].url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            path = StoredImage.saveToInternalStorage(bitmap1, getApplication(), category);
            return path;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Due to async task,it is taking to much time to parse the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to consider:

1. Is the image always the same and always/regularly shown and the app's component; bundle it as a resource or [download it as an apk expansion file](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files) on the first install.
2. Is the image always the same and always/regularly shown; download it into a gallery folder on the device.
3. Is the image temporary but will likely be repeated and shown again for a few days etc duration; use image caching with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/). Glide is the recommended method of image loading by Google.
4. If image is regularly updated and is connected to some web-service (i.e. has a large size, higher resolution); turn down the sizes, resolution and image format to fine-tune image on the server side to keep it ready for mobile download. Read [**Reducing image download sizes**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/network-xfer), from Google's Android documentation and [Automating image optimization](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/automating-image-optimization/).

Hope this helps.

**Remember** there will always be network related delay in download due to its changing speed and other hardware factors.